# Consistency Conditions of the Kolmogorov Extension Theorem

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

[Kolmogorov's extension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem) allows for the construction of a variety of measures on infinite-dimensional spaces, and its conditions are supposedly "trivially satisfied by any stochastic process". However, I'm a little confused about the extent of generality of these conditions.

Following wikipedia's notation, let $\nu_{t_1 \dots t_k}$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb R^k$. The first consistency condition requires that for every $k \in \mathbb N$ and for all permutations $\pi$ of $\{1 \dots k\}$ and measurable sets $F_i \in \mathbb R$, 
$$
\nu_{t_{\pi(1)}\dots t_{\pi(k)}}(F_{\pi(1)} \times \dots \times F_{\pi(k)}) = \nu_{t_1\dots t_k}(F_1 \times \dots \times F_k)
$$

Doesn't this condition imply that all finite-dimensional marginals of the process are exchangeable? If so, then this condition cannot be said to hold for any random process. Am I missing something?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean by "exchangeable"?

Comment: A sequence of random variables is exchangeable, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables, if their joint distribution is preserved under any permutation of indices.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, Kolmogorov's consistency condition doesn't imply that the random variables are exchangeable. If we define

$$\nu_{t_1,\ldots,t_k}(F_1 \times \ldots \times F_k) := \mathbb{P}(X_{t_1} \in F_1,\ldots, X_{t_k} \in F_k)$$

then the consistency condition reads

$$\mathbb{P}(X_{t_{\pi(1)}} \in F_{\pi(1)},\ldots, X_{t_{\pi(k)}} \in F_{\pi(k)}) = \mathbb{P}(X_{t_1} \in F_1,\ldots, X_{t_k} \in F_k). \tag{1}$$

In contrast, exchangeability means

$$\mathbb{P}(X_{t_{\pi(1)}} \in F_{\color{red}{1}},\ldots, X_{t_{\pi(k)}} \in F_{\color{red}{k}}) = \mathbb{P}(X_{t_1} \in F_1,\ldots, X_{t_k} \in F_k). \tag{2} $$

So, in $(1)$ we apply the permutation both to the times $(t_j)_{j=1,\ldots,n}$ *and* the sets $(F_j)_{j=1,\ldots,n}$ whereas in $(2)$ we only apply the permutation to $(t_j)_{j=1,\ldots,n}$.

Comment: Oh OK! Thank you very much, this is very helpful!

Comment: @Azalea You are welcome. If you find the answer useful, you can accept it by clicking on the tick next to it.

Comment: @saz why isn't $\mathrm{(1)}$ trivial? $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\mathbb{P}(B\cap A)$ always